# Changing the target schema on export or import?

Tags: postgresql

I normally do the following for SQL dumps:

```
pg_dump -U username -cOx database > dump.sql
```

And then restore it into a new database with:

```
psql -U username new_database < dump.sql
```

Currently the `database` tables are not in the `public` schema, but a schema named for a user. No reason for it. I think it happened when there was a migration from MySQL to PostgreSQL a few years back using a utility whose name escapes me.

I'd like to move everything into `public`. I know I can do this by editing the `dump.sql`, which is a slow process given the size of the file (which is pretty small in database terms).

Is there a way to do this when exporting or importing a SQL dump?

This is PostgreSQL 13, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this.

You could for example restore the dump into a temporary database, drop the `public` schema there, rename your schema to `public` and then dump again.